# saving data in firebase returns me an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a firebase database.
After an action of the user I create a new ref and set some data:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref(`users/${userID}/likes/${ID}`);
ref.set(ID);
```

I pass the userID and the ID to the function, the values are created correct in firebase but when I download the data, sometimes I have an array instead of a list of objects. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref(`users/${userID}/likes/${ID}`);
```

ref.set(ID);

It looks like you are double nesting whatever ID is. Your reference will create a new route after likes with its name being whatever ID is then you are setting ID (whatever it is) inside this newly created route(which is also an object). If you are trying to create references to what posts a user liked (or anything) package them up client side into an array and THEN set them to users/${userID}/likes..

Here is an example, I am using sign up info, but it is all the same process..

```
let account = {}
        account.email = email.toLowerCase()
        account.uid = authData.uid
        account.username = username



firebase.database().ref('users/' + authData.uid).set({
            account
        })
```

In the example when you lookup a ref snapshot at this users uid you will get a single account object where you could also access the data if you set it as an array.

You could follow this example by...

```
let likedPosts = []
likedPosts.push(new data from user interactions)
firebase.database().ref(users/${userID}/likes).set({
            likedPosts
        })
```

Alternatively, and probably the best way (if you want to use firebase) is to follow this demo and .push to users/${userID}/likes. I don't like this method because it creates an object of objects with unique ID's. To work with this data is difficult because you can't use basic javascript helper functions like map, filter, and reduce.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data